# Retrieve past 1 hour data by filter with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have set of dates stored in a list:

```
var dateList = {
    Wed Jun 06 2018 09:16:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
    Thu Jun 07 2018 09:43:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
    Thu Jun 07 2018 09:47:57 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
```

I want to filter past 1 hour data,
I tried the below condition, but it is not working,

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var hourago = new Date(currentTime.getTime(1000 * 60 * 60));
var newLastOccurred = '';
filteredAppliedData = this.FilterData.filter(function (filterData) {
     return newLastOccurred >= hourago;
});
```

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [isAfter](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) and [subtract](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) methods from the moment API, to filter dates that occurred *after* one hour ago.

```
const oneHourAgo = moment().subtract(1, 'hour')
dateList.filter(d => d.isAfter(oneHourAgo))
```